# Need some overloading info for C#

Tags: c#, overloading

im having trouble with the following and wanted to see if anyone could help me. the details are in the code, but im trying to overload a constructor and the parameter names are giving me an error:

```
using system
    //blah, blah blah

        class Animal
        {
            private string name;
            private string race;
            private double _weight;
            private double _age;


        public Animal(string n,string r, double a, double w)
        {
            name = n;
            race = r;
            age = a;
            weight = w;
        }

            public double age
            {
                get
                {
                    return _age;
                }
                set
                {
                    if (value > 0 && value <= 25)
                    {
                        _age = value;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        do
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Age!\nDog's age: " + value);
                            Console.Write("Please enter dog's age: ");
                            age = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                        } while (_age < 0 && age > 25);
                    }
                }
            }
            public double weight
            {

                get
                {
                    return _weight;
                }
                set
                {
                    if (value > 0 && value <= 60)
                    {
                        _weight = value;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        do
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Weight!\nDog's weight: " + value);
                            Console.Write("Please enter dog's weight: ");
                            weight = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        } while (_weight < 0 && _weight >= 60);
                    }
                }
            }

            public Animal()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Age!" + "\nInvalid Weight!");
                Console.Write("\nInformation for the 1st dog : ");
                getdetails();

            }
            public void info()
            {
                Console.Write("\nInformation for the 2nd dog: ");
                Console.WriteLine("\nName: " + name + ", Race: " + race
                    + ", Age: " + age + ", Weight: " + weight);

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            public void getdetails()
            {
                _age = 1;
                _weight = 1;
                Console.WriteLine("\nName: No Name, Race: No Race" + ", Age: " + _age + ", Weight: "
                    + _weight);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }





            public static void Main(String[] args)
            {
                Animal dog = new Animal();
                Animal dog2 = new Animal(name,race,age,weight);***//HERE'S THE ERROR!
//SO HERE ARE WHERE MY TROUBLES LIE. I CREATED A NEW OBJECT AND I AM TRYING TO PASS
THE ENTERED INFORMATION FROM THE USER TO ONE OF MY CONSTRUCTORS BUT 
IM HAVING A TOUGH TIME DOING IT. COULD SOMEBODY HELP PLEASE?***

                Console.Write("Please enter your dog's name: ");
                dog.name = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Please enter your dog's race: ");
                dog.race = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Please enter your dog's age: ");
                dog.age = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Please enter your dog's weight: ");
                dog.weight = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                dog.info(); 


            }
        }
    }
```

now i know that there are many things that dont have to be written in this code but this is how iam supposed to do it, im just having trouble with the parameters any help please?

Comment: Your question isn't clear but the dog2 object is being created and you are passing undeclared variables into the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You seems to be confusing constructor call and function call  - > `animal(name, race ...)` is just a function in your code so you can't directly invoke it. have a look on how to overload constructors. btw it would be nice to know which language you are using ^^</strike>

Sorry i was analyzing your code with my C++ hat... and in C# you are doing everything pretty much right except passing the correct values as parameters. you are trying to pass the value before they are defined/assigned which is why you are getting the error.
so for the dog2 you might want to do this instead.

```
   public static void Main(String[] args)
            {
                //variable declation
                string name, race;
                double age, weight;

                //variable assigned user inputs
                Console.Write("Please enter your dog's name: ");
                name = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Please enter your dog's race: ");
                race = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Please enter your dog's age: ");
                age = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Please enter your dog's weight: ");
                weight = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                // call of the overloaded constructor with the right parameters
                Animal dog2 = new Animal(name,race,age,weight);

                dog2.info(); 


            }
```

I hope this help, good luck :)

Comment: i am writing in C#. so my Animal dog2 = new Animal(name,race,age,weight) is a function in my code? I declared the variables in class animal and created animal dog2 to pass the information the user inputs in main, to my constructor in class animal and i dont really get how to do that

Comment: no sorry this is c# and  new Animal() construct an object and is not just a function call. you just weren't passing any actual user input to the constructor of the dog2 object

Comment: thanks for the help. i did in fact declare my string and double variables in main but i kept getting the error. Then i saw that you deleted dog. from name,age,race and weight so i tried that and it still gives me errors. im trying to have the user define my parameters but i dont know how to do that.

Comment: could you show the error that you are getting ? i deleted dog in front of name ,age... because what you where doing there was assigning the user input to first dog element and not the second one. ( and it what i think you are trying to do )

Answer (score 0):

Your example has two `Constructors`, a default parameterless `Constructor`, `Animal()` and a `Constructor` that requires **four** parameters `Animal(string n, string r, double a, double w)`.  The signature of the `Constructor` informs you of both the number and `type` of `parameter(s)` expected.

```
Animal dog = new Animal();
```

The above works without complaint as you are using the default parameterless constructor.

```
Animal dog2 = new Animal(name, race, age, weight);
```

The above does not work as you are attempting to make use of the parameterised constructor, however, you are passing it jibberish in the form of `unresolved symbols`.

What you need to be doing is declaring (and instantiating if desired) some variables that will be passed to your constructor:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string name = "SomeName";
    string race = "SomeRace";
    double age = 12;
    double weight = 9001;

    Animal dog2 = new Animal(name, race, age, weight);
}
```

If you need/want your user to define the parameter values passed to your parameterised constructor, then you will need to do something similar to how you have collected user input further down in your example (using `Console.ReadLine()`).

*EDIT:***

**@** *"so what exactly do you mean because i did declare the string and double variables to pass them but it didnt work."*

That bit of your code appears to have either been omitted, or missed.

**@** *"Your saying that i would have to ask for user input inside the constructor of class animal? or create a method that accepts inputs to change the values of the variables passed?."*

You are attempting to create an instance of `Animal` using the parameterised constructor inside the `Main` function, therefore you need to declare and instantiate your variables that will be used as parameters for the `Animal` constructor prior to making the constructor call and inside the `Main` function.

**@** *"like i said i did declare the strings and doubles but i did not assign values to them because like you said i am trying to have the user define my parameters but i am not sure how to do it exactly."*

Your code already has an example of how to obtain user input and assign it to your variables:

```
// You wrote this [:
Console.Write("Please enter your dog's name: ");
dog.name = Console.ReadLine();
Console.Write("Please enter your dog's race: ");
dog.race = Console.ReadLine();
Console.Write("Please enter your dog's age: ");
dog.age = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("Please enter your dog's weight: ");
dog.weight = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

The above requests user input using `Console.ReadLine()` and the value of the user input is then assigned to the associated `Animal` `property`.  So for example:

```
dog.name = Console.ReadLine();
```

The above assumes that there is already a valid instance of `Animal` named `dog`.  `dog` has a number of public `properties` (`name`, `race`, `age` and `weight).  The left side (`left operand`) of the`assignment operator`(`=`) is the object property that you want to assign a value to.  The right side (`right operand`) of the`assignment operator`is where that value is derived.  This could be`Console.ReadLine()`(as in this example), a mathematical calculation or a hard coded value etc.  However the`right operand`is derived, it is`assigned`to the`left operand`.  This is your assignment.

Another example:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Obtain parameter values from user

    Console.WriteLine("Enter a name");
    string name = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a race");
    string race = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter an age");

    // Console.ReadLine() reads values in as strings
    // Therefore you will need to convert the values you want as doubles
    double age;
    while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out age))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The value you entered is not a valid age, please enter a valid age");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a weight");
    double weight;
    while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out weight))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The value you entered is not a valid weight, please enter a valid weight");
    }

    // Create an instance of Animal
    Animal dog2 = new Animal(name, race, age, weight);
}
```

Comment: so what exactly do you mean because i did declare the string and double variables to pass them but it didnt work. Your saying that i would have to ask for user input inside the constructor of class animal? or create a method that accepts inputs to change the values of the variables passed?

Comment: like i said i did declare the strings and doubles but i did not assign values to them because like you said i am trying to have the user define my parameters but i am not sure how to do it exactly.

Comment: I have edited my response in an attempted to answer your comments.